# Symfony 2 FOSUserBundle with different db connection than other bundles

Tags: database, symfony, connection, fosuserbundle

I want to build a site where users can log in register and that stuff. For the User management i use FOSUserbundle. Now i want to use a different db connection for FOSUserBundle than for the other bundles. My config.yml file looks like:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:   default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   "%database1_driver%"
                host:     "%database1_host%"
                port:     "%database1_port%"
                dbname:   "§database1_name%"
                user:     "%database1_user%"
                password: "%database1_password%"
                charset:  UTF8

            user:
                driver:   "%database2_driver%"
                host:     "%database2_host%"
                port:     "%database2_port%"
                dbname:   "%database2_name%"
                user:     "%database2_user%"
                password: "%database2_password%"
                charset:  UTF8

orm:
    default_entity_manager:   default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection:       default
            mappings:
                MyProjectMainBundle: ~
        user:
            connection:       user
            mappings:
                MyProjectUserBundle: ~
```

When i try to load the page i get the error `MappingException: The class 'MyProject\UserBundle\Entity\User' was not found in the chain configured namespaces MyProject\MainBundle\Entity, FOS\UserBundle\Model`.

I followed the documentation for FOSUserBundle exactly and it is working if i use

```
auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
auto_mapping: true
```

in config.yml.
The only thing with this is, it only generates the table like defined in the new entity from the documentation. Only an id field is generated, and not the whole fos_user table like it should.

I know some similar questions have been asked before, but I tried using all the solutions from there and it didn't work. So how can I fix this? Is it even possible? I really need to use seperate databases because my project will use a lot of tables and i don't want it to get too messy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    user:
        connection:       user
        mappings:
            FOSUserBundle: ~
            MyProjectUserBundle: ~
```

Need to add the FOSUserBundle to your mappings to get rid of the entity error

And make sure you have the model_manager_name set in config.ym;

```
fos_user:
    db_driver:     orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class:    Cerad\Bundle\AccountBundle\Entity\AccountUser
    model_manager_name: user
```